# How `[]` works with lambdas

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have this lambda (or is closure the correct usage?) and I understand the usage of `.call`

```
def multi(m)
  lambda { |n| n * m }
end

two = multi(2)
two.call(10) #=> 20  #call the proc
```

But I am trying to understand why/how this works?

```
two.(20) #=> 40 
two[20] #=> 40
```

I don't know whether it should or shouldn't work. Most of the time I have used square brackets with arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation

***[prc[params,...] → obj](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D)***

> ***Invokes the block, setting the block’s parameters to the values in params using something close to method calling semantics.*** Generates a warning if multiple values are passed to a proc that expects just one (previously this silently converted the parameters to an array). ***Note that prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”.***
>
> For procs created using lambda or ->() an error is generated if the wrong number of parameters are passed to a Proc with multiple parameters. For procs created using Proc.new or Kernel.proc, extra parameters are silently discarded.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, `proc.()` is a hack because Ruby doesn't let you define `()` on an object. It's just syntaxic sugar for `proc.call()`.

For your second question, [using square brackets on a `Proc` calls it](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D).